# About user within image/container/host node docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, node.js

I am using docker / node:16 base image to deploy our node web projects.

Yesterday, all of them went bust on one host machine, with the problem within the image (I assume).

We publish images to our internal harbor server, and we are pulling them from the machines to run them.

The same image is still working on our production machine, but the same image no longer works on test machine, and I am afraid to touch the prod server for this reason.

we are using docker-compose files.
Upon `docker-compose up` I get the error:

```bash
print-service_1  | npm ERR! code EACCES
print-service_1  | npm ERR! syscall mkdir
print-service_1  | npm ERR! path /.npm
print-service_1  | npm ERR! errno -13
print-service_1  | npm ERR!
print-service_1  | npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
print-service_1  | npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
print-service_1  | npm ERR!
print-service_1  | npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
print-service_1  | npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 973:970 "/.npm"
```

I can understand the problem here (tho - I haven't updated NPM there, it was still working days ago..)

But my main question is about the user here.

The user:group `973:970` comes from the docker-compose file:

```yaml
    user: 973:970
```

And I am having hard time wrapping my head around this.

I can use a directive `USER node` from the dockerfile (tis user is defined in the node image (https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/feb33de091b1f7c33adc4d52ecbacbd3b2274eeb/20/buster-slim/Dockerfile#L3). I can understand this.

But how comes that he asks to chown -R 973:970 ? within a dockerfile - there could be no such user.. How could I know for the dockerfile - which user will be running this image? Obviously I can't..

Is the user, created and used by the dockerfile completely ignored if specified in dockerfile?

I need more of a conversation about this - so I could understand the problem here..